# Disable multiple statements in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm running a web app backed by ASPX and SQL Server, now I want to disable multiple statements execution, e.g `select 1,2,3; select 1,2,3`

So, can I disable that feature, or do I need to modify the connection string to make it work?

Comment: You can't. That aside, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to protect yourself from SQL Injection?

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith I found that MySQL could disable that feature manually, then I thought about MSSQL. Please also check my reply for Sebastian

Comment: @SebastianMeine Yep, if I did so, in a SQL injection point, the attacker won't be able to run the `exec sp_XX` commands, right?

Comment: Follow standard issue advice on [SQL injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(SQL.105).aspx), stop looking for a simple/magic cure that isn't there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server does not have an option to restrict the number of statements per batch.

While some SQL Injection attacks rely on injecting an additional statement into the batch, others just try to change the statement at hand to their advantage. The first type could be prevented by implementing this idea. However, the second type cannot.

The standard example for SQL Injection is the login query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE user_name = '?' and password = '?';
```

If you use manual parameter substitution and the attacker types

```
admin';--
```

as user name and any password, the app gets the same response from the database that it would have gotten if the real admin had typed in her correct password.

In this attack the batch still only contains a single statement, so your "trick" would not have prevented it.

In general it is better to prevent injection in the first place. Always verify all user input before you use it to build any kind of dynamic statement (not only SQL Statements).

In SQL use prepared statements or stored procedures and use the API functionality to substitute parameter values.

A good starting point for anti-injection patterns is this technet article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx